# C5029 (E) Expected an expression

Tags: c, struct

I am working on a look-up table for a thermistor but I am running into the following error:

C5029 (E) Expected an expression

Here is some information about what environment and tools I am using:
-Renesas RX111 micro-controller
-e2studio program environment using C language
-E1 debugger from Renesas
-Reference: http://coactionos.com/embedded%20design%20tips/2013/10/03/Tips-ADC-Thermistor-Circuit-and-Lookup-Table/

Below is the code I am trying to implement:

```
/**********************************************************************/
#define TABLE_SIZE 24

typedef struct
{
    float x;
    float y;
} dsp_lookup_f_t;

float dsp_lookup_f(const dsp_lookup_f_t * table, float x, int size)
{
    int i;
    float m;
    i = 0;

    // find the two points in the table to use
    while((i < (size)) && (x > table[i].x))
    {
        i++;
    }

    // make sure the point isn't past the end of the table
    if(i == size)
    {
        return table[i-1].y;
    }

    // make sure the point isn't before the beginning of the table
    if(i == 0)
    {
        return table[i].y;
    }

    // calculate the slope
    m = (table[i].y - table[i-1].y) / (table[i].x - table[i-1].x);
    // this is the solution to the point slope formula
    return m * (x - table[i].x) + table[i].y;
}

dsp_lookup_f_t my_table[TABLE_SIZE] = 
{

    { .x= 18373 , .y= -40   }, 
    { .x= 56654 , .y= -35   }, 
    { .x= 87176 , .y= -30   }, 
    { .x= 111321 , .y= -25  },
    { .x= 130338 , .y= -20  },
    { .x= 145291 , .y= -15  },
    { .x= 157048 , .y= -10  },
    { .x= 166307 , .y= -5   },
    { .x= 173618 , .y= 0    },
    { .x= 179412 , .y= 5    },
    { .x= 184019 , .y= 10   },
    { .x= 187698 , .y= 15   },
    { .x= 190651 , .y= 20   },
    { .x= 193029 , .y= 25   },
    { .x= 194955 , .y= 30   },
    { .x= 196521 , .y= 35   },
    { .x= 197801 , .y= 40   },
    { .x= 198851 , .y= 45   },
    { .x= 199716 , .y= 50   },
    { .x= 200433 , .y= 55   },
    { .x= 201029 , .y= 60   },
    { .x= 201526 , .y= 65   },
    { .x= 201943 , .y= 70   },
    { .x= 202292 , .y= 75   }
};

/**********************************************************************/
```

The issue I am having is with the table. I'm not too experienced with designing structs but I used the reference I mentioned previously to help me with this code. I'm not sure if I am missing something obvious, but does anyone have any suggestions to point me in the right direction? I would appreciate any input that anyone has to offer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just needed to removed the ".x=" and ".y=" from the table.

Comment: The `.x =` and `.y =` notations are C99 (or C11) 'designated initializers'.  You may simply need to enable C99 or C11 compilation.  If you're on a Microsoft system, that may require you to install GCC — because GCC does support most of C99 including designated initializers specifically, but MSVC still does not support most of C99 — including designated initializers, AFAIK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler unfortunately, as I recall, it isn't even in C11, but rather GNU C specific.

Comment: @keltar: you recall wrong.  See section 6.7.9 Initialization of C11; it's section 6.7.8 in C99.  It is not a part of C89/C90.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks. I've had a problem with something like that, but can't remember what exactly.

Comment: @keltar: the only GNU extension I am aware of in this area is the ability to repeat an initializer for a range of rows in an array. IIRC, the syntax is: `int a[100] = { [10...30] = 42 };` leaving elements 0-9 and 31-99 as zeros.